# Is there a way to refer to an html element with multiple classes?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following

```
<p class="main yellow">Hello World</p>
```

I would like to write a css element that refers to only elements with main and yellow. Is there a way to do this?

Eg. the following doesn't work, but would be what I'm after

```
.main + .yellow { color:green }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should grab it:

```
.main.yellow { color:yellow; }
```

Though you may get differing results in different browsers. I use [QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/multipleclasses.html) to get an idea of what will/won't work cross browser.

Comment: I think the second gets elements with the class "yellow", that are nested (any depth) within elements with the "main" class

Comment: yeah - you're right - I misread the question, and I've removed that line

Comment: @BlueFish: I believe the order *should* be respected, and as scunlife says the latter class will grab children of the former for space separated classes.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to specify them as

```
.main.yellow { color: green; }
```

No space between the two classes.

Answer (score 1):

does this work for you?

```
.main.yellow{
  color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have already said, what you want is:

```
.main.yellow { color:green; }
```

However, let me quickly explain why your first attempt didn't work. The + keyword refers to a *following* element, i.e. the element after.

Your example would have matched the following HTML...

```
<p class="main">Hello</p>
<p class="yellow">World</p>
```

...and styled the second paragraph (`.yellow`) green. So "`.main + .yellow`" means "select a `.yellow` that is immediately after a `.main`".